# I want to make a dotted grid where each line has unequal overlap

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to make a design like this, which has the same pattern of point distance
[image]

but... my design like this, where the distance is not the same. please help me... thanks before
[image]

Answer (score 12):

The distances of the horizontal lines and the distances of the vertical lines must both be multiples of the sum of the lengths given in the dash-gap list. Otherwise it will look irregular.

Give as many dash and gap lengths. Zero is acceptable. You didn't insert the second gap length, Illustrator sets it as it wants.

An example: dash-gap list 0,5mm/1mm/0,5mm/0mm has sum = 2 millimeters. It allows line spacings 2,4,6,8,10...(etc) millimeters. Here's an image where both horizontal and vertical line spacings are 20 mm:

[image]

Scaling the grid is possible if you set in Illustrator preferences "Scale strokes and effects" ON at least when you scale. Line width can be changed with no harm.

You are not limited to preset dot shapes. Use your own shape as Scatter Brush

[image]

Here a 0,5 millimeters wide square is dragged to the Brushes collection and defined to be scatter brush with 400% (=2mm) repeating period. It's applied to lines which have spacing = 12 millimeters.

Answer (score 8):

I would....

- Draw a rectangle the size you want your entire grid.
- Select this rectangle and choose `Object > Path > Split Into grid` from the menu
- Enter the number of row and column divisions you want and click `OK`
- Set a stoke
- Tick the `Rounded Caps` Option in the **Stroke Panel**.
- Tick `Dashed Stoke` option in the **Stroke Panel**
- Enter `0` in the first `Dash` field
- Enter a value you want *between the dots* in the first `gap` field.

There ya go... dots aligned and all uniform.

[image]

Entering `0` for the dash and using rounded end caps creates "dots" as opposed to dashes.

If you *want* actual dashes rather than dots, adjust the `dash` and `gap` fields.

[image]

If you want more space between dots, adjust the `gap` field...

[image]

If you want larger dots, adjust the stroke weight...

[image]

This creates a series of rectangles with overlapping strokes. But the dots all line up so the overlap in not visibly detectable.

Because dashes *can* be set to align to corners on the Stroke Panel, utilizing a collection of rectangles is actually *easier* for this than using a series of separate, individual, paths.